# Exporting to Excel using .xlsx

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, export-to-excel

I am using a script that exports to Excel.  This script previously worked using mysqli and the Excel extension .xls.

Now I am trying to use the Excel extension .xlsx.  Although the spreadsheet is exported as a .xlsx file, I am not getting any data on the sheet.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
include('../includes/database.php');

global $ts;
$ts = date('mdY-His');

$sql = "SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM table WHERE column1 IS NOT NULL"; 
$stmt = $dbc->query($sql);

header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=GRI&PSSReport_CustomerOnBoarding-".$ts.".xlsx");  
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ");

/*******Start of Formatting for Excel*******/   
$sep = "\t"; //tabbed character
for ($i = 0; $i < $stmt->columnCount(); $i++) {
    $col = $stmt->getColumnMeta($i);
    //print_r($col);
    print_r($col['name'] . $sep);
}
print("\n");

//start while loop to get data
while($rows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)){
    //print_r($rows);

    foreach($rows as $row){
        echo $row . $sep;

    }
    print("\n");
}   
?>
```

I am unsure why the excel sheet is blank. How can this issue be fixed?

Comment: CSV isn't Excel. And at least take a look at the resulting output instead of just observing an empty sheet.

Comment: I commented out the headers, and was able to return the column names and data to  a test page.  Now I need to get that data into the spreadsheet.

Comment: Use https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet

Comment: I just changed .xlsx to .csv and that data exported to the page.  The data is properly separated into their respective cells though.

Comment: @gibberish - but why do you think the above code is failing?  I can change the extension back to .xls and the data comes out just fine.  Why is it the .xlsx is failing?

Comment: @gibberish - Thank you for your input.

Comment: @JohnBeasley the mimetype informs the client what type of file it is. You are not emitting an .xlsx file, but a csv or tsv. Turning it into a .xlsx means actually generating the .xlsx format (which, afaik is at least a bunch of xml files in a .zip file). Servers and client don't magically convert it for you.